# Ruby-Squib svg files not rendering completely

Tags: ruby, svg, squib

I am using Ruby-Squib with self generated .svg vectors.

I'm downloading and amending the vectors, adding some simple text to their top right corners, and then re-saving them as standard .svg files.

When i run the .rb file that references them, the cards are generated correctly, and the graphics are displayed, though the new additions to the vectors, such as the small text, or small coloured icons , are not.

[original svg file] https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPDI.jpg

[How it appears on card]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0mIh.jpg

Note the missing "infinity" symbol.

In other tests i've had only "text" on the top right corner of the svg file, and still this did not appear.

Appreciate any help in determining why this is occurring.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your ruby code?

Comment: Broken svg files would be good too.  Preferably a minimized example that only has the broken bit.  Svg support varies widely between implementations.  I often have svg files from inkscape that won't render properly in Firefox or my file manager.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for broken svg files, I usually render svg files as png by using Inkscape's command-line interface.  Use the generated png files in your squib script.